# STS warnings on @Value tag

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Sts shows the following warning on all my instances of @Value. Is there something incorrect, or can/should the warning be supressed?

Unsatisfied 'required' dependency of type [class java.lang.String]. Expected at least 1 matching bean

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: I was able to recreate the same code by using this... `@Autowired
 public Service(final Process process, @Value("${role}") final String role) {
  this.process = process;
  this.role = role;
 }` It is complain about the `String` being unsatisfied.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in the validation that you should file at: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS. A sample project that reproduces the problem would be great.

In addition to that you can disable the validation in the preferences. I think it is the "Autowire" validation.